# angularjs substring before a specified character url

Tags: javascript, angularjs, url, substring

I have this:

```js
$location.path() // categoria/1-ropa
```

I want just the id (is 1 in this case)

```js
var path = $location.path().substr(10, $location.path().length); 
var idBusqueda = path.substr(0, path.indexOf('-'));
```

with this i do that, but i want know if i can do it in one line?

Greets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My proposal is:

```js
var result = ("categoria/111-ropa".match(/\/(\d+)-/) || [null, null])[1];
```

Comment: Thanks to both, i prefer this because is more restricted.

Answer (score 0):

If you have only one parameter named id , then you can simply use javascript line to get the value:

```
var result = location.search.split('id=')[1];
```